# Why Won't These Villagers Breed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently figured out that you an create villages with lots of doors.  I decided I would try this for myself and made a creative world and built this structure:
[image]

I realized that there weren't any villages nearby so I spawned two in.  Then my problem was that only one of the villagers would have the heart particles above it and they wouldn't breed.  So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one of them has the heart particles, you've done everything correctly. Give them more time and they'll breed.

Answer (score -1):

According to the Minecraft Wiki page on Villagers and how they breed, along with structural requirements, which I believe you met, they also have to be "willing" in a way similar to when you feed cows wheat.

You can make them willing by trading with them (they give off green particle effects when they are made willing). They will not likely immediately seek out a mate however, so you should give them some more privacy after trading.

Comment: Please don't post the *exact* same answer in [two places](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/300671/162442).