# Villagers still not breeding

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I still don't understand why the villagers will not breed. I put a villager in a blockhouse (3 houses one on the other and another house near the top one on a side), gave him enough food,traded with him,and still he has not entered love mode. Then,I spawned another villager near him,and still he has not entered love mode. I even quited and reloaded world. Still he has not.
Notes: I play Minecraft 1.8.7,I looked up on the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villagers),but I did not succeded and I do not use mods on 1.8.7.

Edit: I have already used the multiple doors trick,by adding 2 doors to the building.

Comment: Do not mark this as duplicate,because I looked on other questions and the did not solve my problem.

Comment: Villager breeding is **an incredibly slow and tedious process** - they don't enter breeding mode simply because they've fulfilled all of the criteria. Once the villager meet the requirements to enter Mating mode, they will *occasionally and at random* enter it. It's an infrequent occurrence at best, and then when you consider that *two* villagers have to do it simultaneously? Well, that's why the other questions on this topic indicate that it's not a fast process.. There's a saying: "A watched kettle never boils", and it's appropriate here. Go do something else while you wait...

Comment: how long you waited for?

Comment: I believe when I last did it, it took around 5 in-game days before they lucked out and entered Mating mode at the same time. It does speed up the bigger the village gets though.

Comment: I've read (not sure if it's still true) that adding doors (how the game measures the size of the village) will speed up the process. I made a bunch of 3x3 buildings with roofs, and doors on every side -- maybe 12-15 of them close to the existing prefab village buildings, and within a couple hours, they were doing the needful. Edit: Derp -- it was the wiki where I read that.. hah.. you just didn't mention doors in your post. Try adding a bunch and see if that helps.

Comment: I actually added 2 more doors before. Yeah, I did not posted it,but it is actually a cheat (or a player-advantage bug) and I do not want to cheat. (I will edit the post) @TimS.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't consider it a cheat, especially if you make entire buildings. The game mechanics seemed to be designed so that villagers will never overpopulate a village. So, in order to make the villagers reproduce, you have to give them more space to "live".

Comment: Unarybit has an excellent video on villager breeding found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8we5776o0E . In the video description there is also a world download with a lot of practical information on why breeding might not work for you.
It deals with the number of doors, but what counts a village and what doesn't.

Comment: Well,adding more doors is not really a cheat,to some extent. I saw youtubers with houses mostly of doors.@TimS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't my villagers breed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188494/why-wont-my-villagers-breed)

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

Why the villager don't breed? It depends on how many door you placed, how many villager and how long do you wait.

### Solution

Naturally, it will start breeding soon.
If you couldn't wait much longer, add more door and more villager to the house.

### Notes

- You can only see the love particle when you set the particle to all in Video Option.
- In 1.8 or higher, To breed farmer, you will need them to plant and harvest crops a few time.

Comment: I was testing just on creative to see how it works. Actually,on survival I had 2 villagers and 6 doors in a village.

Comment: So, try to add more door.