# Villager breeding in 1.10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have followed ImpulseSV's design for a villager breeder:

This worked for a while but then stopped after a zombie seige; I repopulated the 2 villagers up top but left the one at the bottom as it was still alive. Now it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Does at least one of the villagers in the farm area have a brown coat without an apron? If so, does he harvest and replant the crops?

Comment: It is a Shepard so no apron. It does harvest crops

Comment: It's possible it may just take some time for the villages to fill up their inventory with food before they start repopulating again. You mentioned that you repopulated the two villages up top, is the Shepard new?

Comment: The Shepard is new as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Why won't my villagers breed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/394920/why-wont-my-villagers-breed) - oops, I meant [Why won't my villagers breed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188494/why-wont-my-villagers-breed)