# Why won't my villagers breed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have build this villager breeding room in a 1.18 minehut server and they are with three villagers (because two didn't work either). I already gave them plenty of food and they have four beds. I already turned on mobgriefing. Why don't they breed?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why won't my villagers breed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188494/why-wont-my-villagers-breed)

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Timmy Jim's comment.

Comment: @pppery It seems that you have mistakenly voted to close this as a duplicate of a different question (Cannot find .minecraft folder).

Comment: I guess that proves that, despite often engaging in botlike behavior, I'm human and capable of making mistakes. I've retracted my close vote, which is in some sense more technically correct for these procedural votes anyway since my primary goal is to get the question into the queue not to count as one of the five users required to close.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Minecraft Wiki, https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Breeding
beds with at least 2 empty blocks above them are required for breeding villagers. It doesn't seem to me that you have 2 blocks of space above the beds you had placed.

Furthermore, willingness plays a crucial role in encouraging the mating of villagers. Villagers can become willing by having either 3 bread, 12 carrots, 12 potatoes, or 12 beetroots in one slot in their inventory. Any villager with an excess of food (usually farmers) throws food to other villagers, allowing them to pick it up and obtain enough food to become willing. The player can also throw bread, carrots, beetroots, or potatoes at the villagers themselves to encourage breeding. Villagers consume the required food upon becoming willing. In short, throwing the villagers food could encourage them to mate. By throwing I mean dropping the food item on the floor by pressing Q so that the villagers would pick them up, instead of placing food in a chest or anything else.

Comment: The bed seems to have 2 empty blocks above them.  Aren't doors the one missing?

Comment: @BunnyMerz you do not need doors any longer. and in the screenshot there is only one empty block above the beds

Comment: @Federico Ahhhh I interpreted as two total blocks above the bed, not a 2 height emptyness above the bed