# Why am I unable to breed villagers in my setup? (1.8.8)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm currently trying out villager breeding, and it's been an hour of me afking and hasn't gotten any new villagers (I started out with 6) l. They are in a room that's 19x19, and I am wanting to know if such a thing as "too big of a room" is possible for them to breed. There's doors on 3 of the walls and there's wheat on almost all the floor of the room, with a 2 block tall pillar over each water source block with torches (there's 9 water source blocks). Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: http://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/how-to-breed-villagers/

Comment: Make sure that one side of each door has an opaque block over it (blocking sunlight) and that the other side does _not_ have an opaque block over it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't my villagers breed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188494/why-wont-my-villagers-breed)

Answer (score -1):

I've had your problem before and I think it's because the villagers aren't 'willing' to breed. The breeder has to be built in a certain way to make them willing and ImpulseSV made a great tutorial for a villager breeder that should work if you do everything he does in the video.

Comment: Could you give more of a text synopsis on what the video suggests? This will allow the answer to still be valid in case the video is ever taken down. (It will likely also result in more upvotes for your answer. Video-only answers aren't really accepted thoroughly here.)

Comment: The basic idea is that villagers need a full inventory to be willing to breed. Therefore, having a farmer villager farm potatoes will allow both of the two villagers to get a full inventory (as the farmer throws potatoes at the other). The way to make this happen is to make the game think that your breeder is a village by placing a third villager next to 6 doors a 7 blocks below the farm in a small chamber.

Comment: @TimS. While I agree, it is also extremely unlikely that ImpulseSV will take down his his video.

Comment: @GrantGarrison I understand, but it's the policy of the site not to post just video links as answers, but rather give a synopsis to go along with it. There have been several videos that have disappeared from the internet due to this kind of situation.