# Why is villager breeding failing in a village?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a village of four villagers. There are about ten beds in the village.

[image: Image of village]

When I feed two of the villagers, they start showing heart particles, but then the breeding fails with cloud particles. Can villagers have a problem pathfinding to a bed behind closed door?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why won't my villagers breed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188494/why-wont-my-villagers-breed)

Answer (score 2):

The beds might not be close enough, or there might not be enough free space above them for the baby to jump.

> [They] can produce a baby only if they have their own beds plus an available bed for the baby, and the beds have two empty blocks above them (there needs to be room for the baby to jump on the bed). If the population cap is met, or the beds are obstructed, angry particles appear above their heads (along with the heart particles), preventing them from mating.
>
> [Minecraft Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Village/Mechanics#Breeding_and_populationv_cap)

Answer (score 1):

Villagers are annoying. They use some odd methods of pathfinding that don’t always work.

1. Take 3 villagers FAR away from the original village
2. Build up a villager breeder (Tango Tek makes a good one on that)
3. Done!

I honestly would not use the original village

Comment: I wanted to breed them in a more natural manner. I've seen the villager breeder designs, but they ruin the purpose of having a nice village.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the villager breeders, give each villager exactly 32 carrots (or bread and so on). Make sure they have at least 4 beds within the same room. (you can change their bed, but that will help with the pathfinding issue)

Hope this helps!