# Why won't survival villagers breed?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I have tried everything from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188494/why-wont-my-villagers-breed), but still, my villagers won't breed.

I entered my survival world temporarily in creative mode to take these screenshots. Here are a couple of pictures of my artificial village:

[image]

[image]

Right now it does not have any crops, as I removed them temporarily. It is supposed to work by getting the adults to breed, and then the new ones fall into a water line and get taken to another part of the map.

In fact, this design works really well on a creative world where I built the prototype. But for some reason, it does not work here.

I have traded with all 4 adults, given them extra bread, and there is at least 1 farm type villager in this "village". There have even been the “willing hearts” above two villagers facing each other at the same time without any results. I have let this sit for days, and still, nothing has happened.

The closest door from the edge of this village is 113 blocks away which should be more than adequate to ensure I do not have village overlap.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried all of the suggestions I could find online.

Comment: If an answer is correct than please click the little green check mark next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the minecraft wiki:

> A valid door is any door within the village radius where the number of "outside" spaces within 5 blocks in a straight line on one side of the door is not the same as the number of "outside" spaces within 5 blocks on the other side of the door. A space is considered to be "outside" if it has nothing but transparent blocks above it all the way to the sky.

I think your issue is that the doors are not all valid. Check to see if some of the blocks have no air above them. Is the cobble completely covering it? Also, you must trade with villagers to make them willing. Try that.

Answer (score 1):

It probably worked in creative because you have the ability to manipulate the breeding system rather than it operating off of the usual requirements you've been attempting to accommodate (so many valid doors, willingness, etc.). I agree with TheGreatDuck that the issue may be that the doors are not valid.

The excerpt they shared was very helpful but it is a bit difficult to understand. The only thing that was easy to understand the first time was the definition of "outside" - which to reiterate is an area above a block that has nothing but air. Basically it's saying the 5 blocks in front of the door cant have the same amount of "outside" blocks as behind the door, which does not appear to be the case with your design. You may want to go back to the drawing board with this in mind.

Comment: I copied the only relevant information from the official minecraft website. If it is not understandable, then someone needs to complain to Mojang. Please do not passive-agressively imply that I wrote an unclear answer.

Answer (score -2):

According to the Minecraft Wiki page on Villagers and how they breed, along with structural requirements, which I believe you met, they also have to be "willing" in a way similar to when you feed cows wheat.

You can make them willing by trading with them (they give off green particle effects when they are made willing). They will not likely immediately seek out a mate however, so you should give them some more privacy after trading.

Comment: Please do not post the *exact* same answer in [two places](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149361/why-wont-these-villagers-breed/300672#300672).

Comment: @Vemonus If it's the same problem with the same solution then why do you care?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck it's clearly not the same problem with the same solution, as one was posted referencing the other saying that the solution to that did *not* solve their problem. Furthermore, it's just bad form to post identical answers on multiple questions.

Comment: @Vemonus Neither of these posts link to the other....

Comment: @TheGreatDuck ah my bad, then it links to a *third* question. Nonetheless, if two questions can be solved by an identical answer, they're more than likely duplicates of each other and the same answer does not need to be posted twice.

Comment: @Vemonus that is a fair point. :-)